# How to distribute weights according to the width of UIView with Objective-C

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview

I'm trying to do something like `LinearLayout` does in iOS, distribute weights depending the Layout. In this case, I've got 4 views (3 `UIView` and one `UILabel`. My scope is giving the same width to all of them depending the superview's width, and set the frame depending of it.

so in `viewDidLoad` I execute this command:

```
[self.view1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0 * self.view1.superview.frame.size.width/4,
                                self.view1.frame.origin.y,
                                self.view.frame.size.width/4,
                                self.view1.superview.frame.size.height)];

[self.view2 setFrame:CGRectMake(1 * self.view2.superview.frame.size.width/4,
                                self.view2.frame.origin.y,
                                self.view.frame.size.width/4,
                                self.view2.superview.frame.size.height)];

[self.view3 setFrame:CGRectMake(2 * self.view3.superview.frame.size.width/4,
                                self.view3.frame.origin.y,
                                self.view.frame.size.width/4,
                                self.view3.superview.frame.size.height)];

[self.label setFrame:CGRectMake(3 * self.label.superview.frame.size.width/4,
                                self.label.frame.origin.y,
                                self.view.frame.size.width/4,
                                self.label.superview.frame.size.height)];
```

but on iPhone 6 I get:

[image]

How do you, guys, redistribute the weights?

Thank you very much in advance.

Rafael.

---

**EDIT**

I've just discover that calling super.view.frame.size.width doesn't give me the full width... why ?

Comment: why don't you use auto layout by setting view1width to equal container width with multiplier 0.25 and so other views.

Comment: that property was unknown for me... I'm beginning with iOS development. I'm going to try that, ok? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you use auto layout by setting view1width to equal container width with multiplier 0.25 and so other views

This is a link demonstrating how to have propotional constraints

http://makeapppie.com/2014/11/25/proportional-sizes-in-autolayout/